# SQL: SELECT with equals before LIKE

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I need to query a SQLite database for items that either match a given string, or are `LIKE` `query%`.  However, it's not as simple as

```
SELECT id, type, number FROM roads WHERE number = '12' OR number LIKE '12%'
```

I need all *equal* matches to come before the *`LIKE`* matches.  I picture there being an `AS` in there somewhere and ordering by it, but I'm not sure how it would work.  I want to avoid making two queries if possible.

Comment: if they are always the same string, coulnd't you just do an `order by length(number)` ?

Comment: Ahhh, that might work, might it?  It won't always be the same string, but then I would just omit the `=` condition.

Comment: then i would change your sample to `WHERE number = '114' or number like '12%'` to make it more challenging (edit: cade's solution still checks out)

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't quite understand.  Yes, it will always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this syntax is supported on Sqlite, but here's an idea:

```
SELECT id, type, number FROM roads WHERE number LIKE '12%'
ORDER BY
   CASE
      WHEN number = '12' THEN 0
      ELSE 1
   END
```

Comment: That looks like the answer, I'll try it.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the unnecessary condition.  You must have been in a rush to answer :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, type, number
FROM roads 
WHERE number = '12' OR number LIKE '12%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN number = '12' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, type, number 
   FROM roads 
  WHERE number = '12' 
UNION
SELECT id, type, number 
   FROM roads 
  WHERE number LIKE '12%'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id, type, number 
                           FROM roads 
                          WHERE number = '12' );
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using this method?

Comment: An alternative interpretation of the spec, "all equal matches to come before the `LIKE` matches," to mean, "only get me `LIKE` matches when there are no equal matches." So the advantage is that you get less data are more targets too but only if meets the requirements, of course.